# Autoscroll overflow text in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, mxgraph, draw.io

I want to have autoscroll on label if it overflows it's container(effect like this: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa ). Label on SVG is rendered as foreignObject tag that contains value wrapped into two divs.
I tried to override getLabelValue function, after loading mxGraph, so it wrap label value into one more div with necessary style, but then label is rendered in top left corner of SVG instead of element position.

```
window.mxCellRenderer.prototype.getLabelValue = function(state) {
        return (
            '<div class="scrolling-text">' +
            state.view.graph.getLabel(state.cell) +
            '</div>'
        );
    };
```

CSS:

```css
.scrolling-text {
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateX(-100%);
        }
    }
```

I manage to get rid of foreignObject with `window.mxClient.NO_FO = true;`
That way the label div is outside of SVG, it's position is right, but it's wrapper div lost it's dimension so label is not visible.

Important points:

1. Diagram is created using draw.io, and then it's displayed with mxGraph.
2. Label value will be changed with mxValueChange event, and the animation shouldn't reset after change.

How to implement such effect with given constraints?